# Hibernate: Criteria API: Query entities which do not contain a specified element in a CollectionOfElements?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Let's say I have the following two classes; User and Location. I want to create a DetachedCriteria to query the user table, and return all users who do not have a location with the name "xyz".

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @CollectionOfElements
    Set<Location> locations;
}

@Entity
public class Location{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Column
    String name;
}
```

The following code will return all users who DO have a location with name "xyz" set:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
dc.createCriteria("locations")
     dc.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "xyz"));
```

If I change to Restrictions.ne(), that doesn't work, because it will only return users who actually have locations set. Also, if there are a bunch of locations set for a user, it will duplicate that user over and over.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using the entities **User** and **Location** as described in your original post:

1) Check if the associated **locations** is empty.

```
Junction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.isEmpty("locations"));
```

2) Create an associated criteria for **locations** using a **LEFT_JOIN** and an alias to be used in the "**ne**" restriction. The LEFT_JOIN is required so we still get **User** records back even if the **locations** relationship is empty.

```
userCriteria.createCriteria("locations", "loc", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
or.add(Restrictions.ne("loc.name", "xyz"));
```

3) Add the disjunction to the the original **User** criteria.

```
userCriteria.add(or);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use some combination of `Restrictions.and()`, `Restrictions.not()`, `Restrictions.or()` and `Restrictions.in()` to get your inverse-logic to work right. Check http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html - it can definitely be done!

To ensure you only get at-most-one `User`, use a `Distinct` projection (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Distinct.html) via the `Projections.distinct()` factory method (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html)- i.e.:

```
dc.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")));
```

Something like that should do what you need.